# TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined everytime I'll reload the webpage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Getting the users collection from firestore:

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState([])
 useEffect(() => {
        if (currentUser) {
          const unsubscribe = db
            .collection("users")
            .doc(uid)
            .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
          const arr = [];
          arr.push({
            ...snapshot.data(),
          });

          setUsers(arr);
        });

      return () => {
        unsubscribe();
      };
    }
  }, [currentUser]);
```

I can already retrieve the data with this:

```
 const userItems1 = users[0][1]?.items;
 let ar = [];
 for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(userItems1)) {
 ar.push(key, " ");
```

and then display the data in the screen with this:

```
<li>{ar}</li>
```

All is well, however, it has an error every time I'll reload the webpage

> TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined

Does it have something to do with `currentUser`?

I'm getting the currentUser from my useSelector:

```
const mapState = ({ user }) => ({
  currentUser: user.currentUser,
});

 const { currentUser } = useSelector(mapState);
```

Any idea on how to fix this? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **`useEffect` runs after the first render, not before it and your state is `[]`**

It would be similar when you are executing this:

```js
[][0][1]
```

**Try to place some conditions before you execute them like:**

```
const userItems1 = users[0]?.[1]?.items;
 if (userItems1) {
 let ar = [];
 for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(userItems1)) {
 ar.push(key, " ");
}
```

Also to check your arr before rendering it, because it will be undefined in the initial render:

```
{ar && <li>{ar}</li>}
```

Comment: How would I be able to fix this?

Comment: As I just edited my answer, place some conditions before go on and do your magic. It will be available on the 2nd render.

Comment: Thank you, it does work. However, now, it was `<li>{ar}</li>` that does not work. It says "ReferenceError: ar is not defined"

Comment: Yeah, because `ar` also not available on your first render. Check it before render: `{ar && <li>{ar}</li>}`

Comment: still the same error, is it because it's inside the `for`?

Comment: Very likely, since I do not see the rest of your code.

Comment: you are still seeing the error because you have ar which is a const and it is block scoped variable . The variable dies once your if block ends .

Comment: @Shyam what should I do to fix it? Should I just put the `ar` outside the condition? It seems to work though